# How to merge divergent branches in git

Tags: git

Everything was on the master branch.
We made a change. It wasn't working.
We went back three commits and created a branch to test out another idea.
That worked.
Now we want the branch to be master.
I thought we would merge them, but we don't need anything in the three commits on master.
How to proceed?

Comment: `reset` your master branch 3 commits back, then merge the branch with master. If you do not want to lose the 3 unwanted commits in master for some reason, you can make a new branch on master first.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a hard reset on the `master` branch to the other branch:

```
# from master
git reset --hard other
```

Alternatively, if you know the SHA-1 hash of the head of the `other` branch, you could also hard reset to that:

```
# from master
git reset --hard 1a2b3c4d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard @~3
git rebase <new branch that works>
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you want to purge your failed attempt from the version control history,
go with the [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75954948/7204912).
But if you want to keep the commit history, or you simply can't force push to the master branch, you can do the following which will create an additional commit for the `revert` and then `merge`:

```bash
git checkout master 
git revert HEAD~3 
git merge your_other_branch
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit the merge strategy

```
git checkout new_branch
git merge --strategy=recursive -Xours master
git checkout master
git merge new_branch
```

Alternatively, you can roll back the changes from your master branch and then rebase the new branch on to master.

Edit:
To add to the last statement, the commands would be:

```
git checkout master
git revert HEAD~3
git rebase new_branch
```